# for loop with variable as input list

Tags: bash

I would like to put below check in a for loop but do not know how to put the variables as input list, just like $A,$B,$C

```
A="file name1.txt"
B="file name2.txt"
C="file name3.txt"

if [[ ! -f "$A" ]]; then
    echo "file $A not exist"
fi

if [[ ! -f "$B" ]]; then
    echo "file $B not exist"
fi

if [[ ! -f "$C" ]]; then
    echo "file $C not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Try `for f in file1 file2 file3; do if [[ ! -f $f ]]; then echo "file $f not exist"; fi; done`

Comment: I'd start by using an array instead of a bunch of different variables.

Comment: I'd use `-e` instead.

Comment: You definitely _can_ write `for file in "$A" "$B" "$C"; do if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]; then ...`, but _why_ would you make that extra work for yourself instead of using an array?

Comment: Good suggestion, I missed the quote so it not work for me! let me try your code!

Comment: Or `-s` to ensure the file exists and is non-empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
A="file name1.txt"
B="file name2.txt"
C="file name3.txt"
for file in "$A" "$B" "$C"; do
    if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]; then
        echo "file $file not exist"
    fi
done
```

The use of `[[` is not POSIX and supported only on ksh, zsh, and bash. It does not require a `fork()` and is, in general, safer. You can substitute `[` and `]` respectively for a POSIX compliant script.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES_TO_CHECK_ARRAY=( "file name1.txt" "file name2.txt" "file name3.txt"  )

for current_file in "${FILES_TO_CHECK_ARRAY[@]}"
do

  if [[ ! -f "${current_file}" ]]; then
    echo "file ${current_file} not exist"
  fi

done
```